# Unexpected behaviour of "source devel/setup.bash"

Tags: ros, source, ros-package-path, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

ROS: Indigo Turtle

Bash: Terminator

Hello,

I have encountered an undesirable behaviour while working with ROS related to sourcing workspaces. First of all I have two workspaces which contain similar packages. The workspaces are: **~/r2d2_CL/...** and **~/c3po_CL/...**     .
I had had no problems installing packages, launching nodes and so on, up until today.

Before, I could source either workspace with `source devel/setup.bash` while being in  **~/r2d2_CL/...** or **~/c3po_CL/...** . As a result **ROS_PACKAGE_PATH** would contain the proper workspace in which I sourced.

But now something strange happens. Whenever I source now, in either workspace, **ROS_PACKAGE_PATH** contains *both* workspaces. The output of `printenv | grep ROS` is:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/bzad/c3po_CL/src:/home/bzad/r2d2_CL/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/bzad/c3po_CL/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/bzad/r2d2_CL/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

You can see, that both workspaces are sourced. This has undesirable effects. For example: When I work in **~/r2d2_CL/...** and type in the terminal `roslaunch vrmagic_camera camera.launch`, ROS executes the launchfile which is located in the workspace **~/c3po_CL/...** .

My questions regarding this problem are:

1. How could this happen? Before the problem occured I have installed another package in the workspace **~/r2d2_CL/...** . Nothing more.
2. How can I revert this, so that sourcing will lead to one sourced (desired) workspace again.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235196/unexpected-behaviour-of-%22source-devel/setup.bash%22/) by [Behsad Ghanei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26974/behsad-ghanei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be that you inadvertently have built your `c3po` workspace while having sourced the other and vice versa.

Start a clean terminal, then remove the `devel` and `build` folders in both workspaces. Now source the distro `setup.bash` and rebuild `c3po`. In another terminal, the same with `rd2d`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Behsad Ghanei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26974/behsad-ghanei/) on 2016-05-25**:
Thanks for the quick advice, I am going to try that out now.

Edit: It worked, I understood, what went wrong. Thank you!